# How would you go about identifying body parts and type of injuries from text data?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I was kind of posting this to get some ideas, but I wanted to go through some text and figure out how to tag body parts and injuries. Any idea how I could do this?

For example if I had this text: "Wizards guard John Wall will undergo surgery to repair a ruptured left Achilles tendon. The procedure, which has yet to be scheduled, will be performed by Dr. Robert Anderson in Green Bay, WI. Wall is expected to return to full basketball activity in approximately 12 months from the time of the surgery."

And I wanted to extract John Wall and left Achilles tendon how do you guys think I could go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use NLTK or Spacy packages for Python.

https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-with-nltk-and-spacy-8c4a7d88e7da

Comment: The NLTK library is only a part of speech tagger. It will annotate an input string with identified noun, verbs and adverbs. The problem with natural language is, that the inner structure follows domain specific knowledge which have to be formalized in an ontology. The better tool would be Protege which is an ontology builder.

Comment: which would mean that you need to build an ontology especially for your application, -> sports injuries